# Using different times for different narrative purposes

Tags: language, narrative, timelines

I'm writing a biography. And I want it to be written in English, although I'm not a native speaker. Can I use different times to highlight different narratives, like this:

1. Present - for describing events from point of view of the participants.
2. Past - for analysis from the author's point of view.
3. Future - for spoilers.

Is it a good idea for narrative in general? Also, is it ok for native English speakers?

Comment: By "Times" do you mean "Tenses", as in past tense, present tense, future tense? If so, that's why they exist. Use them.

Comment: If you're not confident with the various usages of tenses in english, maybe you could consider writing the biography in your native language and then investing in a professional translator.

Answer (score 1):

Check this great summary on [how to use the different tenses in english](https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/tenses/)

I can also advise you to use [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) to check your overall document, style, grammar and spelling. The free version is interesting, and if you need more there is a paid version.

I hope this will help !